# Call method from abstract class when abstract method called in the derived class

Tags: c#, xna, listener

I'm making a user interface in XNA with a custom control setup. I have a base abstract class called `Clickable`, this contains methods that are run when various actions happen, I.e; `OnClick`, `OnRelease`.

I have tried to implement listeners into this, i use the below two methods to get this to work:

```
public void RegisterClickListener(Action<Vector2> ClickMethod)
{
    listners.Add(ClickMethod);
}

public void OnClickMethod(Vector2 pos)
{
    foreach (Action<Vector2> func in listners)
        func(pos);
}
```

`RegisterClickListener` adds the method passed in the parameters to a list of methods to be called when the `OnClickMethod` method fires. `OnClickMethod` simply iterates through the list and calls each method.

I need a way to be able to call `OnClickMethod` each time my abstract method `OnClick` (bellow) is called. Currently i have to to manually invoke `OnClickMethod` each time i use `OnClick`, which is not ideal.

```
 public abstract void OnClick(Vector2 pos);
```

Is there a way i can do this while keeping OnClick abstract? Or will i have to take off the abstract and call base each time i use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Template method pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx). Create a method which acts as a template(does some steps in fixed order), then give the client options to override only small portion of it.

```
public void OnClick(Vector2 pos)
{
    OnClickCore(pos);
    OnClickMethod(pos);
}

public abstract void OnClickCore(Vector2 pos);
```

Now `OnClick` is a template method which defines set of rules that need to be invoked when it is called.

Comment: @LexWebb Take a look at my code carefully. `OnClick` is nomore abstract or `virtual`. I added `OnClickCore` method, that's what derived classes needs to implement and they **don't** need to call `OnClickMethod`

Comment: Ah, i think i see what you mean. So i would call `OnClick` from the class that listens to mouse clicks, and do my `OnClick` functions in the derived class in the `OnClickCore` method?

Comment: @LexWebb Yes, exactly. Derived classes don't have control over `OnClick` they only have access to `OnClickCore`. As soon as it finish executed `OnClickMethod` will be called(when there is no exception :()